# Would a unique progress bar with ng-file-upload multiple (one-by-one) uploads present a race condition?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, concurrency, race-condition, ng-file-upload

Here I'm using the awesome [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) from Daniel Farid, and following the [multiple files one by one on file select](http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/2vq88rfs/136/) approach (to address some compatibility issues/requirements I have here):

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
    $scope.uploadFiles = function(files, errFiles) {
        $scope.files = files;
        $scope.errFiles = errFiles;
        angular.forEach(files, function(file) {
            file.upload = Upload.upload({
                url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
                data: {file: file}
            });

            file.upload.then(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    file.result = response.data;
                });
            }, function (response) {
                if (response.status > 0)
                    $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            }, function (evt) {
                file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * 
                                         evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
        });
    }
}]);
```

This way, Every file object will show it's own progress bar. However, I want to show something like a "general progress bar" too, which will be incremented by a function like this:

```
    $scope.totalProgress = function (value) {
        $scope.totProgress += value / $scope.files.length;
    };
```

Naively thinking, this will work, but I'm affraid that I'll incur on race conditions at `$scope.totProgress += value / $scope.files.length;`.

So, Would a unique progress bar with ng-file-upload multiple (one-by-one) uploads present a race condition?

If yes, How could I correctly implement a mutex/semaphor over `$scope.totProgress` variable?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: javascript is single threaded and you won't need semaphor. Can you explain how and when are you calling totalProgress function?

Comment: Hi @danial , thank you for answering me =). I'll bind `$scope.totalProgress()` to a html `label` or something else.

Comment: But when do you call totalProgress? it needs to have a value parameter.

Comment: Hi @danial, I'm sorry for the "over-year" late response. I would call totalProgress function in each progress event. This way, the "value" parameter would be "file.progress" property. Thank you in advance.